# Why to skip first character of URL

Tags: javascript, node.js, server

I am learning some node.js from [Eloquent JavaScript](https://eloquentjavascript.net/20_node.html) where I found this piece of code whose purpose is to decode the url requested to a server and to resolve it relative to the server’s working directory:

```js
const {parse} = require("url");
const {resolve, sep} = require("path");

const baseDirectory = process.cwd();

function urlPath(url) {
  let {pathname} = parse(url);
  let path = resolve(decodeURIComponent(pathname).slice(1));
  if (path != baseDirectory &&
      !path.startsWith(baseDirectory + sep)) {
    throw {status: 403, body: "Forbidden"};
  }
  return path;
}
```

The book doesn't say anything about the `.slice(1)` in the line

```
let path = resolve(decodeURIComponent(pathname).slice(1));
```

Why not do just `slice()`? Why skip the first character of the decoded URL before comparing it with the path of the current working directory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first character of the pathname will be `/` and the goal is to use a relative path from the current working directory and not an absolute path starting at the root of the file system.

Comment: But I created a basic server with the line `console.log(process.cwd())` and I got a path beginning with `/home` with the `/`. So you would need the `/` in the decoded url

Comment: Why? You aren't concatenating the path to the cwd yourself are you?

Comment: Maybe I am being a bit confused (because I am totally new to servers and node.js), but isn't `!path.startsWith(baseDirectory + sep)` trying to establish whether `path` starts with `baseDirectory + sep`? And if `baseDirectory` aka `process.cwd` starts with a `/` and we trim the leading `/` in `path`, isn't the comparison useless?

Comment: The `/` is being sliced from the `pathname` but `path` is the result of passing that through `resolve`.

Comment: Oh you are right. I guess this is the crucial point. I will check the documentation for `resolve`. Thank you for everything.